# Падает приложение Android Studio при переходе между Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

MainActivity

```
package com.example.car_55;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity5 extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText UMN;
int UMN1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        OnButtonClick();
        EditText el1 = findViewById(R.id.El22);
        UMN1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());



        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }





    private void OnButtonClick() {

        int a = 0; // Начальное значение диапазона - "от"
        int b = 100; // Конечное значение диапазона - "до"

        int random_number1 = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 1-го числа
        System.out.println("1-ое случайное число: " + random_number1);

        int random_number2 = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 2-го числа
        System.out.println("2-ое случайное число: " + random_number2);

        int random_number3 = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 3-го числа
        System.out.println("3-е случайное число: " + random_number3);

        int UMN1 = random_number1 *random_number2;



        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.el1)).setText(random_number1 + "" );
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.El33)).setText("" +random_number2);



    }
}
```

Логи:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.car_55, PID: 2681
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.car_55/com.example.car_55.MainActivity5}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Name"
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Name"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
        at com.example.car_55.MainActivity5.onCreate(MainActivity5.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
Application terminated.
```

Я думаю, что проблема в этой строке, т.к., когда я ее убираю всё работает,

UMN1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());

но не знаю как решить данную проблему. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод parseInt() преобразует число в строковом (String) виде в int. Например:

```
Integer.parseInt("123")
```

Вернет число 123 типа int. А если передать строку не являющуюся числом, например:

```
Integer.parseInt("asdf")
```

Получите NumberFormatException, как в вашем случае, так что вызываете этот метод в блоке try - catch

```
try {
    UMN1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
} catch (Exception e) { 
    //Выполните необходимые действия в случае ошибки
}
```